# Logo is set as h1 tag - how to remove this (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

in my wordpress blog using theme "hueman" I added a logo.

I looked with firebug in the code and saw that the logo is set as h1 tag on every page. I would like to remove this because I want the titles in the text/content to be h1.

Unfortunately I can't find the code and don't know what exaclty needs to be removed?

Using firebug it says "h1....site-title..." but in the css file I only find a page-title that is defined with h1. Do I just have to delete the "h1" here?

Thanks for helping me
BR
Heidi

Comment: This will be defined in actual page templates. Since it's occurring on every page, it's probably in **header.php**

Comment: If you can share your code of Header.php we might help you.

Comment: how can I post my header.php here? If I copy it in its too long...???

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the hueman theme... however if you look in the folder wp_content/themes/hueman/header.php

In word press themes the logo and top menu are normally rendered in this file and is called by the wp_header() function with in your templates.

Comment: in the header.php there is unfortunately no h1 setting.